# No content in mails sent to PHP application from iPhone

Tags: php, email, imap

I just tried sending an email from my iPhone to my web app. I received it, the subject and the date stamp was correct. Although the message of the email was just empty..

This is how I get the message content:

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($stream, $email_id);
if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
$part = $structure->parts[1];
$message = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,2);
$message2 = imap_fetchbody($stream,$email_id,1);
if($part->encoding == 3) {
$message = imap_base64($message);
} else if($part->encoding == 1) {
$message = imap_8bit($message);
} else {
$message = imap_qprint($message);
}
echo $message;
```

Does anyone know why this happen? As said, it only happens when I send emails from my phone. to my email account.

Comment: At least format your code properly man.

Comment: Yeah, but that is still not properly formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the mail from the phone is a multipart message (with one part, which is an odd way to use the multipart type if you ask me). Test the content-type, I'm fairly sure it'll be multipart/whatever instead of text/plain.